# Why is Magento Observer is not called?

Tags: magento-1.9

Config file:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config>
  <modules>
    <Mmymodul_Autocoupon>
      <version>0.1.0</version>
    </Mmymodul_Autocoupon>
  </modules>
  <global>
    <helpers>
      <autocoupon>
        <class>Mmymodul_Autocoupon_Helper</class>
      </autocoupon>
    </helpers>
  <events>
      <sales_order_invoice_pay> <!-- identifier of the event we want to catch -->
        <observers>
          <sales_order_invoice_pay_handler> <!-- identifier of the event handler -->
            <type>model</type> <!-- class method call type; valid are model, object and singleton -->
            <class>Mmymodul_Autocoupon_Model_Observer</class> <!-- observers class alias -->
            <method>capture</method>  <!-- observer's method to be called -->
          </sales_order_invoice_pay_handler>
        </observers>
      </sales_order_invoice_pay>
    </events>
    </global>
</config>
```

Observer class:

```
<?php
class Mymodule_Autocoupon_Model_Observer
{
    public function capture(Varien_Event_Observer $observer)
    {
        Mage::log('Test log', null, 'mylog.log', true);


    }  
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

**config.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config>
    <modules>
        <Mmymodul_Autocoupon>
            <version>0.1.0</version>
        </Mmymodul_Autocoupon>
    </modules>
    <global>
        <models>
            <autocoupon>
                <class>Mmymodul_Autocoupon_Model</class>
            </autocoupon>
        </models>
        <helpers>
            <autocoupon>
                <class>Mmymodul_Autocoupon_Helper</class>
            </autocoupon>
        </helpers>
     </global>
     <frontend>
         <events>
             <sales_order_invoice_pay> <!--Im not sure for this event-->
                 <observers>
                     <Mmymodul_Autocoupon_Model_Observer><!--Class to your observer, Path= Model/Observer.php-->
                         <type>singleton</type>
                         <class>autocoupon/observer</class> 
                         <method>capture</method>
                     </Mmymodul_Autocoupon_Model_Observer>
                 </observers>
             </sales_order_invoice_pay>
         </events>
     </frontend>
</config>
```

**Observer.php**

```
<?php
class Mmymodul_Autocoupon_Model_Observer extends Varien_Event_Observer {

    public function capture($observer){
      ...
    }
}
```

Comment: Should work, was just missing `models` node, but 1.) better use `extends Mage_Core_Model_Observer`. 2) no need for `<type>singleton</type>`. It's singleton by default. 3) you can call `Mmymodul_Autocoupon_Model_Observer` as you want. Its just an alias that has to be unique for given event.